# Windows Service doesn't stop 'Starting'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service

I've created a service and an installer. I've installed my service on the computer. In the services screen, I can see that the service is Starting. It won't stop Starting, I can't pause it, nothing. The only thing I can do is to deinstall.

I've tried attaching Visual Studio to the proces, but nothing really happens. How can I debug this service? I'd like to know what is going on.

Comment: This usually happens if you have too much/all of your code running inside your `OnStart` handler - you're meant to kick things off in there and then *return*. It's only once you return that your service is considered started.

Comment: How do I return there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if you have too much/all of your code running inside your [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) handler - you're meant to kick things off in there and then return. It's only once you return that your service is considered started.

You'd typically create one or more new [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)s that run the code you want running all of the time, [`Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx) them and then return. Or create objects that implicitly run their own threading (e.g. WCF's [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx)).

Then, it's your job in [`OnStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx) to shut them down gracefully - e.g. [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and then [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) on those threads.

e.g your class might look like this (not tested)

```cs
public class MyService : ServiceBase {
   private ManualResetEvent _stop = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   private Thread _worker;

   public override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    _worker = new Thread(DoStuff);
    _worker.Start();
   }

   public override void OnStop() {
    _stop.Set();
    _worker.Join();
   }

   private void DoStuff() {
    while(!_stop.WaitOne(0)) {
     //Do something useful here.
    }
   }
 }
```